# Custom Date Format for Bootstrap-DatePicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone guide me for formatting date in **Bootstrap-DatePicker**.

And I used [Eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker).
Here my codes at JSP..

```
<div>Date : </div>
<input type="text" style="width: 213px;" class="datepicker" >
```

And at my JavaScript file...

```
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy (D)',
    autoclose: true,
    keyboardNavigation : true ,
    endDate : dateFormat(date, "dd/mm/yyyy (ddd)"),
    daysOfWeekDisabled : [0]
});
```

Output that I want to get as like **27/07/2013 (Sat)** .

But output that show from my code as **27/07/2013 (Sat**

I can't see close bracket **" ) "**. Any Suggestions?

Comment: I used setting endDate format by using javascript from http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sure you are using a old version. You must use the last version available at master branch:

https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: I had tested with that.. you said I used old version and you sure.. Yah. you right. Thanks for guiding me and your valuable times..

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the new version. I had the same issue. All old issues have been solved by using the github version.

Comment: I don't know why I can't set format ? :-( I m using the latest version

Comment: I use version 1.4.0, but format still doesn't work. My jsfiddle sample: https://jsfiddle.net/79qbuk6m/2/ . Date is printed to console on selection.

Answer (score 21):

Perhaps you can check it here for the LATEST version always

http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    startDate: '-3d'
})
```

or

```
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    startDate: '-3d'
})
```

Comment: yes , Thanks for giving me latest update site . I assume it may always be updated.

Comment: @Dimi I have to use the defaults setting, or my format declaration gets overridden......

Answer (score 3):

```
var type={
      format:"DD, d MM, yy"
};
$('.classname').datepicker(type.format);
```

Comment: Output that I want to get as like 27/07/2013 (Sat) .

Comment: kyay zu tin bar tal khin bya... :)

Answer (score 1):

I solve it editing the file bootstrap-datapicker.js.

Look for the text bellow in the file and edit the variable "Format:"

```
var defaults = $.fn.datepicker.defaults = {
    assumeNearbyYear: false,
    autoclose: false,
    beforeShowDay: $.noop,
    beforeShowMonth: $.noop,
    beforeShowYear: $.noop,
    beforeShowDecade: $.noop,
    beforeShowCentury: $.noop,
    calendarWeeks: false,
    clearBtn: false,
    toggleActive: false,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [],
    daysOfWeekHighlighted: [],
    datesDisabled: [],
    endDate: Infinity,
    forceParse: true,
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    keyboardNavigation: true,
    language: 'en',
    minViewMode: 0,
    maxViewMode: 4,
    multidate: false,
    multidateSeparator: ',',
    orientation: "auto",
    rtl: false,
    startDate: -Infinity,
    startView: 0,
    todayBtn: false,
    todayHighlight: false,
    weekStart: 0,
    disableTouchKeyboard: false,
    enableOnReadonly: true,
    showOnFocus: true,
    zIndexOffset: 10,
    container: 'body',
    immediateUpdates: false,
    title: '',
    templates: {
        leftArrow: '&laquo;',
        rightArrow: '&raquo;'
    }
};
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to override the defaults directly in bootstrap-datapicker.js. You can change the format by simply writing $.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = 'dd/mm/yyyy'; in any other js file that loads after bootstrap-datapicker.js