# Change b:datepicker date format

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using bootstrap datepicker.

```
<b:datepicker id="journeyDate" placeholder="Journey Date"
              value="#{openSearchController.otRouteBean.toTime}"/>
```

The default date format date is `mm/dd/yyyy`.

I want to change it to `dd/mm/yyyy`.

I have used this JS. But no use.

```
<script>
     $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Not working like that

Comment: See also : http://stackoverflow.com/q/17896176/656243